# How to build semantically immutable entity with many fields

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have entity with 25 fields. It has not any logic, just store values.
It's build with abstract builder. I don't want something change this entity after build.
I want to make all fields final, but i don't want make 25-params constructor.
What pattern should I use in this situation?
Now I think about package-local setters, but it's worse, than syntax checking for all values setting in final fields.
I can't pack this fields in 2-3 objects

Comment: Sounds to me like you need Scala. :)

Comment: What happens if you make all of the fields final and public?

Comment: @barnesjd - Actually, it might not be as straightforward as you think since [Scala has a 22 field limit for case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7910). I suppose you could declare a normal class with a 25-parameter constructor and put `val` in front of each item—but that doesn't really solve the OP's problem since that's exactly what he's trying to avoid! (I really like Scala, but its fancy language features don't really solve the problem here.)

Comment: Another solution but not too good so thats why is a comment not to OOP as answer provided... could be having a Map with <field,value> and in when you setProperty if it was setted then don't do anything, cause your object has no behaviour only state could be a possible solution, but i like better the builder pattern.

Comment: The described case is a classical anti-pattern that violates almost every principle of OOP. I'd recommend to refactor your class and break it down into proper classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see three main options:

1. Have a private class only the builder knows about, and a public interface with only getters. The builder gives out references using the interface, not the class.
2. Have two classes, one mutable (which is a bit of a messenger class) and one that's immutable, which accepts the mutable one in its constructor and grabs its fields.
3. Have the class have reasonable default values for all fields, and then have setters which return a *new* instance of the class with that field set. The downside here is that to build a 25-field instance, you end up creating ~24 throw-away objects, depending on how many of the reasonable defaults you need to change. ;-)

Comment: A builder pattern, an adapter pattern, and a prototype pattern. Good examples all the way.

Answer (score 8):

Have the `Builder` class as a `static` nested class in your `Entity` class.  Then the `Builder` class can set the fields directly, and you won't need setter methods or a *n*-arg constructor in `Entity`.

```
public class Entity
{
   // Just one attribute and getter here; could be 25.
   private int data;

   public int getData() { return data; }

   public static class Builder
   {
      // Just one attribute and getter here; could be 25.
      private int theData;

      public Entity build()
      {
         Entity entity = new Entity();

         // Set private field(s) here.
         entity.data = theData;

         return entity;
      }

      public Builder setData(int someData)
      {
         theData = someData;
         return this;
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
Entity entity = new Entity.Builder().setData(42).build();
```